# How to match extension in any path level with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

i need to a request mapper that match only images in any path level.

For example, it must match;

```
http://localhost:8080/filename.jpg
http://localhost:8080/figs/filename.jpg
```

I tried regex and non-regex way;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{reg:(?:\\w|\\W)+\\.(?:jpg|bmp|gif|jpeg|png|webp)$}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

But, it matches with `http://localhost:8080/filename.jpg` but not matches with `http://localhost:8080/figs/filename.jpg` or `http://localhost:8080/anypathlevelNtimes/
figs/filename.jpg`

How can it matches with all path level and file extension is only image.

**Edit: It is OK now**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/**/{extension:(?:\\w|\\W)+\\.(?:jpg|bmp|gif|jpeg|png|webp)$}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: So your problem solved..

Comment: You should answer your question and accept it so that it no longer appears as unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Solution proposed by [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/994387/rahman-usta):

```
@RequestMapping( //
       value  = {"/**/{extension:(?:\\w|\\W)+\\.(?:jpg|bmp|gif|jpeg|png|webp)$}"}, //
       method = RequestMethod.GET //
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@RequestMapping("/spring-web/{symbolicName:[a-z-]+}-{version:\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d}{extension:\\.[a-z]+}")
public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String extension) {
    // ...
}
```

[reference https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html